# What is best monitoring tool for Tornado as Async container?

Tags: python, monitoring, tornado

Tornado web can be used wth WSGI or ASYNC container. There are numerous solutions for WSGI container.
Most appealing solution by now is RPM Lite, but it requires Tornado to run in wsgi mode which I do not want. I need solution that will fully monitor Tornado Async application.

EDOT: Thanks @Graham for reading between lines, I've been expecting people that understand topic would have an answer.

Comment: If you are going to mark a question as negative say why. In this case it looks to be because the question wasn't explained well but at the same time those people who marked it as negative show they don't know much about the Python web world to read into the question what was being asked. If you you don't understand ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is a bit obscure but the assumption here is that you are asking what web application performance monitoring tools exist. In this case you are asking for one that will work with the Tornado ASYNC API vs the WGSI container that sits on top of Tornado web server.

You mention 'RPM Lite' which would interpret as being New Relic web application performance service. For that, as you found, only WSGI applications running on Tornado are currently supported and not the ASYNC API of Tornado. Some investigation of support for ASYNC Python web frameworks has been done but Tornado API wasn't used as test case for that and so not known when/if the ASYNC API may be supported.

As for alternatives, it depends on what you want to get out of this and is where you need to expand on the question. If you are more after tracking web traffic then you can alway using Google analytics or tools that extract details from web server logs.

If you are specifically after tools which can instrument the actual web application and tell you what is going on inside of it, including show time taken in database, web externals, etc, like New Relic does, then there isn't currently any other options that I know of for ASYNC systems and in particular Tornado ASYNC API.

Comment: The latest Python Agent does support Tornadohttps://docs.newrelic.com/docs/python/new-relic-for-python.